# SharedPreferences to keep session

Tags: android, session, sharedpreferences

I make an app with some activities.
The first is the login.
If I login correctly, I pass to the second activity, and I want download a stream (like twitter), but I cannot keep the session.

I saved user & pass in sharedpreferences, how can i keep the session througt all activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the data back from shared preferences.

Careful though using shared prefs for logins.  You would have to encrypt it.  I can not remember if this is possible with shared prefs.

Shared preferences is generally not the best solution when it comes to logins.